# Wheel of Fortune design

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, problem-solving

In the case of a generalized Wheel of Fortune, the Expected Value is simply the dot-product of a Probabilities vector with a corresponding Values vector:

$$E(W)=\sum p_i v_i$$

By way of example, a three-slice wheel with two slices having a $25\%$ chance of "hitting" and the third slice having a $50\%$ chance of hitting, using values for the three slices respectively of 1, 4, 10 would yield :
$$E(W) = (.25\cdot 1) + (.25\cdot 4) + (.50\cdot 10) = 6.25$$

If the goal were to have the same $ E(W) $ but make the probabilities for each slice as close in value as possible, one could define a simple error function acknowledging that perfectly equal slices would each have $\frac{1}{3}$ probability of hitting.

$$Err(p) = \sum ( p_i - \overline{p} )^2$$

This error could never be zero unless the $E(W)$ value were changed to 5, which is not desirable.

$$E(W) = \left(\frac{1}{3}\cdot 1\right ) + \left(\frac{1}{3}\cdot 4 \right) + \left(\frac{1}{3}\cdot 10\right) = 5$$

An alternate error function may be considered without regard to the mean probability:

$$Err(p) = \sum p_i^2$$

These $p_i$ values are probabilities:

$$\sum p_i = 1$$

$$0 < p_i < 1$$

Question: Given $E(W)$ and each value on the Wheel of Fortune $(v_1 \ldots v_n)$ as a priori constant, is there a well known way to establish $(p_1 \ldots p_n)$ such that either error function $Err(p)$ is minimized? Its safe to assume the error function is continuous.

I don't think simplex can work because of the constraints about probabilities summing to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error functions appear to be the same if one expands out the $(p_i - \bar p)^2$ term.  But this seems to be a standard constrained optimization problem: $\min \|p\|^2$ subject to $\langle \vec{1},p\rangle = 1$ and $\langle v,p\rangle = \mathbb{E}[W]$, so you can just solve it with Lagrange multipliers.  Let $w := \mathbb{E}[W]$, so the Lagrangian is

\begin{align*}
\max_{\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in \mathbb{R}} \min_{p \in \mathbb{R}^n} \big( \langle p,p \rangle - \lambda_1 (\langle \vec 1,p\rangle -1) - \lambda_2 (\langle v,p\rangle -w)  \big).
\end{align*}
The first order condition for $p$ implies $p = \frac{\lambda_1}{2} \vec1 + \frac{\lambda_2}{2} v$, so after plugging in, our goal is now
\begin{align*}
&\max_{\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in \mathbb{R}} \frac 14 \big( -\lambda_1^2 \langle \vec1,\vec1 \rangle - 2 \lambda_1 \lambda_2 \langle \vec1,v \rangle - \lambda_2^2 \|v\|^2 + 2 \lambda_1 + 2 \lambda_2 w  \big) \\
=& \max_{\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in \mathbb{R}} \frac 14 \big( -\lambda_1^2 n - 2 \lambda_1 \lambda_2 \langle \vec1,v \rangle - \lambda_2^2 \|v\|^2 + 2 \lambda_1 + 2 \lambda_2 w  \big).
\end{align*}
The first order conditions for $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ then give the system
\begin{align*}
-\lambda_1 n -  \lambda_2 \langle \vec1,v \rangle + 1 &= 0 \\
-\lambda_2 \|v\|^2 - \lambda_1 \langle \vec1,v \rangle + w &= 0,
\end{align*}
which can then be solved to find $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.

Comment: How would I go about applying this to the situation where the expected wheel value is $E(W)=12$ and the Wheel Values vector $v=(1,2,3,5,10,25,50,100))$?

Comment: @Veldaeven Plug in $w=12$ and compute out $\langle \vec1,v \rangle$ and $\|v\|^2$, solve the $2$x$2$ system for $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, then plug in to the $p = \frac{\lambda_1}{2}\vec 1 + \frac{\lambda_2}{2}v$ formula.  I added an arrow to clarify when I mean the vector of all 1s instead of the scalar 1.

Comment: I'm sorry I may seem slow here- I watched some videos on Lagrange multipliers, and cannot see how these can address the fact that the $p$ vector are probabilities, where each $0<p_i<1$. When I try to apply the methods I've found, I frequently end up with negative probabilities. Can you help me clarify what I should be educating myself on?

Comment: The general way of solving this is with Karush–Kuhn–Tucker conditions. However, this case is particularly nice since the objective function is quadratic and all the constraints are linear.  Solving this kind of question falls under quadratic programming.